# C# find nearest or closest int value from multiple object

Tags: c#, linq

This my problem i make some listview for display result data:

```
data| X  |  Y |
A   | 20 | 15 | 
B   | 10 | 20 |
C   | 30 | 28 |
```

and case is my `CurrentX` is 25 && my `currentY` is 27.

From the data, the nearest value from `CurrentX` is 20 & 30 but nearest value from `CurrentY` is 28.

Then the correct what data must be selected or shown is C because X = 30 nearest from Current X(25) & Y because nearest from CurrentY(27)

How wrong select data is A because is same have nearest X and current X but Y and Current Y is to far

I'm really confused with this I'm already trying to find closest using linq but it only just finds 1.

so any i dead for this for make result showed is C

Please really I need your help for this

I try this :

```
dataX = int.Parse(ListView.SubItem[1].Text);

List<float> numbersX = new List<float>() { dataX };

var resultX = (from n in numbersX
               where n >= dataX
               orderby n select n).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is this ok? I can found nearest X, but when I do the same method for finding in the data Y, it's going to be wrong.

Then how to find X and Y ?

Comment: Distance is sqrt(x^2 + y^2)  Since closest can be positive or negative you need to use absolute.  So you would use something like  Math.Abs(math.SQRT(Math.Pow(x-25,2) + Math.Pow(y-27)))

Comment: @jdweng - Distances based on the formula are always positive as the squaring eliminates negatives. `Math.Abs` is unnecessary because there are no negatives and `Math.Sqrt` is unnecessary when comparing the relative distances of two points. `Math.Pow` should be avoided as it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by closest points, but you can find the nearest or closest value based on two parameters (X and Y), by calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the current point (CurrentX, CurrentY) and each point in your data. The point with the smallest distance is the nearest point.

[image]

```
// your points list
List<(string, int, int)> data = new List<(string, int, int)>
{
    ("A", 20, 15),
    ("B", 10, 20),
    ("C", 30, 28)
};

// current point coordinates
int currentX = 25;
int currentY = 27;

// Calculate the Euclidean distance between the current point and each point in the data then order by this distance and take first value
var nearest = data
    .OrderBy(p => (p.Item2 - currentX) * (p.Item2 - currentX) + (p.Item3 - currentY) * (p.Item3 - currentY)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) method orders the points in the data list by their Euclidean distance to the current point. The [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) method then returns the first (i.e., nearest) point in the ordered list.

Maybe you actually need a [taxi metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) between two points, not Euclidian distance. Then just change the method of calculating the distance inside the `OrderBy`.

[image]

```
var nearestTaxiDistance = data
    .OrderBy(p => Math.Abs(currentX - p.Item2) + Math.Abs(currentY - p.Item3))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a white background on your equation. In dark mode it is a bit hard to read.

Comment: I'd also suggest doing `.OrderBy(p => (p.Item2 - currentX) * (p.Item2 - currentX) + (p.Item3 - currentY) * (p.Item3 - currentY))` as you are then dealing with basic numerical operators. `Math.Sqrt` is completely unnecessary for the comparison and `Math.Pow` is slow.

Comment: Note that the Euclidean metrics is just one of many possible metrics. You might e.g. also use the "Taxi metrics" `Abs(q1-p1) + Abs(q2-p2)`. Without knowing what "nearest" exacly means there is no unique answer.

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestions I updated my answer with your advices